# How do I rotate a geometry around a specific point?

Tags: javascript, opengl, webgl

I make rotations around its own axis but I can't understand how to do it when I want figures to rotate around other points not necessarily within its geometry.

Comment: Rotating around a models origin is simply multiplying each vert in the model by a RotMatrix. Now instead construct one matrix M by multiplying TransToPoint then RotMatrix then InvTransToPoint. Then multiply each vertex by this M. This will rotate your model around the point specified by TransToPoint.

Comment: [this *might* help](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html).

Comment: It's kind of hard to given answer without more context. What are you trying now?

Comment: I only want the logic about matrix rotations, specifically I want to rotate a sphere around another sphere.

Comment: [This might be helpful then](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html).

Answer (score 1):

The standard transformation order, SRT, assumes that the geometry is centered at (0,0,0) and that is the the pivot point for rotation. For example, if you have a cube geometry ranging from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1), rotating the cube rotates it around the center (0,0,0). If the cube geometry is placed at say (9,9,9) to (11,11,11), then when you apply SRT, you are no longer rotating it from the center of cube (10,10,10) but still rotating from (0,0,0). The effect is that the cube is rotated around a point outside of its geometry.

The point is that a translation of the geometry vertices before rotation will change the center of rotation. Thus, before the rotation transformation, do a translation of geometry vertices (its usually called offset or anchor point btw) to rotate around a specific point.